# do I lose my N2O if i pay for a few months and then go off the paid plan (back to free)

Tags: nitrousio

I currently have a free nitrous.io account with a single box that runs off of N2O I acquired simply by signing up and getting other people to sign up.  If I start on the $10/mo pay plan (so that I can avoid having my box automatically shut off) and after a few months decide I don't want the pay plan, will I lose my box and/or N2O, or will I just revert back to the situation I have now?

Comment: Sounds like a question for their support/billing teams?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it should be addressed to the company that sells the product.

Comment: I just sent them email with the text of the question above.  I posted here since their "ask a question" button on help.nitrous.io redirects to stackoverflow.com.

Comment: I would think billing questions would have some kind of contact information on their site, since that is not what we are here for.

Answer (score 0):

This question is out of scope for StackOverflow support and should probably be locked, but as it hasn't been yet, here's the answer:

You **do** lose your N2O. In their help area under [Billing/N2O Renewal](http://help.nitrous.io/billing-n2o-renewal/) it says the following:

> The N2O you acquire through your subscription is yours to keep while you remain subscribed. You will only lose purchased N2O capacity if you cancel your subscription.

That being said, it's not clear if you also lose boxes that would exceed the free level of N2O. I suspect it might let a box linger but they'll probably catch on quickly and ask you to remove a box before they do it for you.